# Validation error. What's wrong here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
    validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :title, uniqueness: true
    validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
        with:   %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)$}i,
        message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG, or PNG image.'
}
end
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

The provided regular expression is using multiline anchors (^ or $), which may present a security risk. Did you mean to use \A and \z, or forgot to add the :multiline => true option?

Apparently the error exists on line 5.

I am extremely new to Rails. It's my first day, actually. What is the problem and how do I go about fixing it? Thanks for your time.

Comment: The answer is in your error message: use `\z` instead of `$` in `with: ...`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Working through the examples in a book.
This was the code that worked for me:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
    validates :title, uniqueness: true
    validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
    validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format:{
        with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
        message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG or PNG image.'
    }
end
```